# PHPMailer loads a while, then gives 500 - Internal server error

Tags: php, iis-7.5, phpmailer, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to setup a php page to automatically send a verification email.  I would like to use the gmail smtp servers, and everywhere I've looked suggests to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).  I installed it and used the following example code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once ("incl\PHPMailer\PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "mypassword";
$mail->SetFrom('myemail@gmail.com','Me');
$mail->AddAddress("ToAddress@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Verify your email";
$mail->Body = "Thank you for signing up.  Please verify your email using the link below:";
$mail->IsHTML (true);

if($mail->Send()){
    echo "Success";
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

When trying to access the page via Firefox, the page will load for a few minutes, then give this error:

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

The server is **Windows Server 2008** R2 Standard running **IIS 7.5** and **PHP Version 5.5.8**.  I can access all other pages without issues, but trying to call `$mail->Send()` seems to be timing out or something.  I know this because I commented every line and slowly added pieces back in and `$mail->Send()` is the line that causes the behavior.

My Google abilities are failing me here as I simply cannot figure out how to make this work.  Any ideas on what might be wrong?

**Update**

I opened the server log then tried loading the page again, but no new errors were added to the log.  However, I noticed the following errors from today in `System32\LogFiles\httperr1.log`

```
2014-10-27 06:29:21 1.161.23.122 3148 212.83.145.123 80 HTTP/1.0 CONNECT mx2.mail2000.com.tw:25 400 - URL -  
2014-10-27 10:10:12 95.183.244.244 33553 212.83.145.123 80 HTTP/1.1 GET / 400 - Hostname -
2014-10-27 11:25:25 207.38.185.197 51157 212.83.145.123 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /tmUnblock.cgi 400 - Hostname -
2014-10-27 12:46:21 1.168.221.158 7952 212.83.145.123 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
```

**UPDATE 2**

I am positive that my gmail account details are correct and have tested sending from it using Thunderbird on the server.  When trying to sent without secured methods, as suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579546/phpmailer-loads-a-while-then-gives-500-internal-server-error?noredirect=1#comment44275276_26579546) I get this error:

> MAIL FROM command failed,550,5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated

My PHP Mailer version is 5.2.9 and I've now also tried the following:

- Using `\\` in file paths instead of `\`

  - No change
- Including `class.phpmailer.php` instead of `PHPMailerAutoload.php`

  - `Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\incl\PHPMailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 1195`
- Using ssl over port 465

  - `SMTP connect() failed`
- Sending with a hotmail address over port 25 with `$mail->SMTPAuth = false;`

  - `MAIL FROM command failed,550,5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated`

**Update 3**

After reloading the problem page, I checked through the Event Viewer and saw a new entry in Windows Logs -> System:

> PHP Error : syntax error, unexpected BOOL_TRUE in C:\PHP\php.ini on line 101

That line is:

> php_flag   display_errors  on

Comment: Error 500 is meaningless by itself. You should find a meaningful error message in your web server logs. Either that, or set `display_errors` to true in your script or php.ini to make it visible. This is not specific to PHPMailer - it's true for any PHP fatal error.

Comment: I tried adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of the script but it did not change the output.  Updated question with some details from the log file.

Comment: If you're seeing 500 errors in your browser, but nothing is being logged, something is wrong with your web server config. The errors you've shown are 400 (bad request) errors. You should also try turning up error reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @Synchro I tried adding `ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL');` on the page as well as `error_reporting = E_ALL` in php.ini but neither changed the error message.  Can you point me in the right direction for how I can verify my server config?

Comment: `error_reporting` is a function - use exactly what I posted - what you put will cause a 500 error by itself!

Comment: Replaced the `ini_set` with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and there is no change in the output.

Comment: Well if that is the entirety of your script, the only thing in there that could cause a fatal error (the code works fine for me) is the `require_once` not finding the class. Try putting the absolute path to the autoloader in there, and check it really exists.

Comment: @Synchro If I remove the `$mail->Send()` then the page loads fine (I assume failure to find the file would error at `require_once ("incl\PHPMailer\PHPMailerAutoload.php");` or `$mail = new PHPMailer();` lines.

Comment: That's true. In that case it may be that you're missing the openssl extension - check output from `phpinfo();`

Comment: @Synchro Looks like that might be it: `OpenSSL support  disabled (install ext/openssl)` but the php.ini has `extension=php_openssl.dll` enabled.  I double checked that this is the same php.ini that is listed under `Loaded Configuration File` for `phpinfo()` output.  I also copied the `php_openssl.dll` to the same location as php.exe but phpinfo keeps saying OpenSSL is disabled.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have done everything described in the [Notes](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php) section...? That might resolve your SSL issue and make this work.

Comment: `php_openssl.dll` should be present in the `ext` directory for it to work (e.g. `C:\Program Files\PHP\ext`). Also for OpenSSL you may wanna check if you have `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` present somewhere in your Windows PATH (e.g. `C:\Windows\System32`) - some nasty problems could also arise concerning wrong versions of those.

Comment: @RobertRossmann I can confirm this, problem still persists.

Comment: @Levit `php_openssl.dll` exists in `C:\php\ext`.  There is no PHP folder under `C:\Program Files`.  Does there need to be?  Neither `libeay32.dll` nor `ssleay32.dll` exist in `C:\Windows\System32`.  Both exist in [3 other locations](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kaGfd.png)

Comment: It is fine to have it just under `C:\php\ext`, if you have php installed in `C:\php`. You might wanna check though, if `C:\php` is part of your windows path environment variable, because if not those two other files will not be found by the system.

Comment: @Levit `C:\php` is double-checked as the environment variable in path

Comment: Just another thought: Did you already try to send from an email address that does not require smtp authentication, so you know for sure that the problem lies there?

Comment: @Levit I have not tried sending from a non-SMTP address.  I'm not sure how to set this up and my searching is not turning anything up.  Do you have a link I can use as a guide?

Comment: Providers which allow unencrypted sending are getting fewer since google heavily criticised this, and published a list of those in mid 2014. But I think hotmail/live.com is one that still supports it, if you don't have an account there, you could register one, and then try with settings like `$mail->SMTPAuth = false; $mail->Port = 25;`. You could actually also try it right away with your gmail address - although not supported by gmail - it might at least give you a different error.

Comment: @Levit Tried changing it to your suggestion (commented out `$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";` and `$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";`) but gmail and hotmail both give this new error: `MAIL FROM command failed,550,5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated`

Comment: Dear David your gmail acount ascess setup requested action and authenticated.

Comment: Well that looks pretty good! Seems like sending would probably work unauthenticated (just that google does not support it, what this new error just reflects). If there would have been still an internal server error, the problem would have been somewhere else, but now you can at least be pretty sure that this whole issue is SSL related (or at least authentication related). In short: We just have to figure out why the openssl module is not being loaded ...

Comment: This could be an IIS setup issue, but from your error log in System32\LogFiles\httperr1.log you get an HTTP Error 400. "The request hostname is invalid" try to check it in MX toolbox first to see if exists. http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3amx2.mail2000.com.tw&run=toolpage

Comment: $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html'; add these lines after $mail->IsSMTP();

Comment: I am not able to find the php error_log entries in the question. Kindly add the same. Try wrapping the send command with a try catch block, probably there might be some info.
Regarding the last update, You don't need php_flag in php.ini. Please cross check

Comment: @kranthi117 wrapping in a try-catch does not change anything. I'll try commenting out php_flag when I get back to a computer.

Comment: @PeterDarmisadding those 2 lines did not change output.  As for the log, the machine that loads the page is given a 500 Internal server error. I will look into MX toolbox later since I'm unfamiliar with it and would rather not try to figure it out on my phone.

Comment: @kranthi117 Commenting out `php_flag display_errors on` and running `iisreset` the problem page now just outputs php source code (as do all the other pages)

Comment: @PeterDarmis MX Toolbox seems to be confirming that it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're dealing with bunch of issues and here is a checklist: you're having issues with ssl, the actual mail software and credentials. It became an issue of 3 from one main issue and I'm guessing you don't either have your credentials typed in correctly or your open ssl isn't setup and you're also having issues using the mail software.

**535 535 5.7.3 Authentication Unsuccessful** means auth is unsuccessful, check your credentials username and password.

**550 error code, it means that the receiving system could not deliver your email to the user to whom it was addressed because the mailbox is unavailable.**

There are plenty of other solutions to resolve your issue. Why don't you try something more simple instead of using the autoload **PHPMailerAutoload.php**. Create a new file and place the code below, create a message body (test_message.html) and call it from the browser to test gmail smtp with the gmail credentials. This is a snippet from PHPMailer on how to use it with gmail smtp and it shouldn't go wrong if you have everything filled in correctly.

```
<?php
    require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
    //include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

    $mail             = new PHPMailer();

    $body             = file_get_contents('test_message.html');
    $body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                               // 1 = errors and messages
                                               // 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "yourusername@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
    $mail->Password   = "yourpassword";            // GMAIL password

    $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

    $mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

    $mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp (Gmail), basic";

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

    $mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
    $mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo "Message sent!";
    }
    ?>
```

If you're getting user auth error, then your credentials aren't typed in 
correctly. If that's not the issue, you'll get an ssl error if you're not using the right port.

If there are software issues with include, you should try something better.

I was debating this morning if I should should **PHPMailer**, ended up using **Swiftmailer** which worked right after I installed it with PHPComposer.

My Internal mail server is extremely picky and has ton of firewall settings and rules on hardware and software level and I was surprised it didn't give me any problems; the emails were being sent right away without any problems on port 587.

```
require_once 'vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.hellog***.com', 587)
  ->setUsername('apache@hellog***.com')
  ->setPassword('apa******')
  ;
```

This is what you need for gmail:

```
$transporter = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
  ->setUsername($this->username)
  ->setPassword($this->password);

$this->mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transporter);
```

If none of what you like, you can try phpgmailer: 
https://github.com/GregDracoulis/LectureBank/tree/master/phpgmailer

here is an example on how to use it: 
http://www.vulgarisoverip.com/2006/10/13/update-send-email-with-php-and-gmail-hosted-for-your-domain/

this class is dedicated for gmail use.

**If all your problems and issues relate to openSSL, you should follow the steps below:**

**1. Make sure the OpenSSL module DLL file is included in the PHP installation:**

C:\user>dir \local\php\ext\php_openssl.dll

Directory of C:\local\php\ext

php_openssl.dll

**2. Create the PHP configuration file, `\local\php\php.ini`, if it does not exist:**

```
C:\user>copy \local\php\php.ini-production \local\php\php.ini

    1 file(s) copied.
```

**3. Enable the OpenSSL module by editing the configuration file with a text editor. You need to remove the comment maker (;) on two configuration lines:**

```
...

; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "ext"

...
extension=php_openssl.dll

...
```

That’s it. You should be all set setting up openSSL on your Windows IIS WebServer. Follow these options and steps, it could be your issue.

Comment: I know my credentials are correct as I can log into the account from anywhere else and send and receive email, this includes Mozilla Thunderbird client on the server with the issues.  I did not have `extension_dir = "ext"` uncommented, but after enabling it and running `iisreset` the output is the same.  Trying to [install Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/download) gives error mentioned in **UPDATE 3**.  PHPGMailer gives `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPGMailer::From()`.

Comment: what is your php version and how are you including these files? do you have the lib setup correctly in a directory where its accessible by your php script?

Comment: **PHP Version 5.5.8** and including using `require_once('incl\phpGMailer\class.phpgmailer.php');` which is where I put those 3 files.  PHPMailer is same as in my question which I assume is working because the page is fine until the `$mail->Send();`

Comment: so you checked if you have openssl installed on your server?

Comment: `C:\php\ext\ ` contains `php_openssl.dll` and the folder `openssl` but `phpinfo()` states: `OpenSSL support | disabled (install ext/openssl)`

Comment: ahh, you need to load php_openssl.dll. just for now, in your code before you execute the mail script, use or put dl('php_openssl.dll'). dl — Loads a PHP extension at runtime

Comment: Adding that to the php page gives `Call to undefined function dl()`  Apparently [this has been disabled since 5.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163525/call-to-undefined-function-dl)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is slashes ( \ )

Edit

```
require_once ("incl\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailerAutoload.php");
```

Comment: Changed the code use \\ instead of \ and get the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with you code, and i have only changed this line :

```
require_once ("incl\PHPMailer\PHPMailerAutoload.php");
```

by this one :

```
require_once ("incl\PHPMailer\class.phpmailer.php");
```

And it was worked successfully.
Also you should keep attention about your PHPMailer version and your PHP version.
Have you tried to send an email with not secured method ?
Are you sure that your google credentials are valid ?

**UPDATED**
From the command line of your server, what is the output of this command and how much time that it takes to respond

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

Comment: Making your suggest change results in this error: `Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\incl\PHPMailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 1195`  As for your other questions, I will update my question with these details.

Comment: Response from telnet command: `200 mx.google.com ESMTP i15sm10941378wjq.22 - gsmtp`

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you are running into the same issue that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163462/zend-smtp-mail-crashes-after-100-mails) ran into. Google actively frowns on people using Gmail as their own personal SMTP server.

http://www.labnol.org/internet/email/gmail-daily-limit-sending-bulk-email/2191/

> Google also limits the number of email messages that you can send through your Gmail account in a day. If you exceed the daily quota, Google may temporarily disable your Gmail account without any warnings and you may have to wait for up to 24 hours before you can regain access to your Gmail mailbox.

I could see an error like that potentially producing a 500 error.

Comment: I doubt this is the issue since I cannot even send a single email, but good to know.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments to the question, it seems pretty clear that this issue is **OpenSSL** related.

You mentioned that you already have `extension=php_openssl.dll` uncommented, but `phpinfo()` does show it not beeing loaded.

*Some thoughts:*

- Have you restarted the webserver, after uncommenting the openssl php module in your `php.ini`?

  This is the really obvious one, but still worth mentioning. The `php.ini` is loaded on start-up, and not doing a service restart is simply a common mistake.
- Check the value of `Loaded Configuration File` in `phpinfo()`

  If this is not the same location than the `php.ini` which you have edited, it also becomes clear why it has not been loaded. Also following lines from `phpinfo()` might be worth checking.

  - Configuration File (php.ini) Path
  - Loaded Configuration File
  - Scan this dir for additional .ini files

There are other things too which can be done like uninstalling and reinstalling OpenSSL, but it might be good to check these more obvious things first.

*Further thoughts:*

- Checking the error logs

  For php the path can (again) be found in your `phpinfo()`. Look for the value of `error_log` and check the latest entries, right after you tried to reload your page.

  Also you may wanna check the log files of IIS. If you don't know the path look in the IIS Manager, select the computer on the left pane, and in the middle pane, go under "logging" in the IIS area. Usually these will point to something like `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles` or `C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles` with a subfolder like `W3SVC[x]` where `[x]` is the website ID. (Will be just `1` if you only have one page, otherwise check the top level websites folder in IIS Manager, view the lists of sites in the right hand pane, it's the App ID)

Comment: I remember running `iisreset` many times but just to be sure I made sure the line was uncommented and ran it again.  No change.  As for your second point: `Loaded Configuration File: C:\PHP\php.ini`  This is the same as the one I've been editing. `Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows` (which may be the issue?)  `Scan this dir for additional .ini files: (none)`

Comment: @DavidStarkey: Since your `Loaded Configuration File` is the one you are editing, this should be fine (altough you can try around with copying it to the Windows path, etc. but it really should(!) have no bearing). `IISReset` also is correct to restart your web services. I added a third bullet point concerning error logs ... you may want to check this one.

Comment: `phpinfo()` for the log record is `error_log | no value | no value`.  As for IIS error log, I don't seem to have the option...  Added some details about the Event Viewer output to question.

Comment: Also, trying to set a location using `error_log = "C:\Windows\temp\php_errors.log"` does not change the output.

Comment: Wow this is really a tough one oO. Well, error logs would be extremly helpful, so let's tackle that first. Have you also checked those two locations mentioned above (`C:\inetpub\logs\...` and `C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\W3SVC1`)? As for the php error log, have you also set `log_errors = On` and possibly `error_reporting = E_ALL` (but this one should not really matter, since you have it set in your php code at the very beginning as well).

Comment: @DavidStarkey: Hey, I just saw your last question update (3) that you already got an error in the EventViewer! In your php.ini it is supposed to be simply be `display_errors = on`!! What you have (`php_flag display_errors on`) is actually something you would put in a `.htaccess` file instead. Try to change that, and see if it loads your `php.ini` correctly.

Comment: Removing `php_flag display_errors on` and setting `display_errors = on` in the php.ini file makes it so all outputs are php source code, even after iis restart.  Putting it back i while keeping the `display_errors = on` results in no change in output.  I'm not familiar with server setup and I'm unable to find a .htaccess file on the server.  I did find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1436171/1618257) related to this, though I quickly ended up beyond my understanding.

Comment: @DavidStarkey: Well it seems that up until now the ini has not been loaded completely because of the error in it. So the question is, what else is in there that might make an issue of things. Or alternatevly - if you see a lot of "warnings" etc. it might just be that you now really see all the errors, since we just enabled this (if it actually is not php sourcecode, but errors you see). Also you might wanna check the EventViewer again. Also try loading a "default-ish" php.ini (= rename yours, and put it in it's place), and see if that loads correctly (if yes, try to JUST enable openssl there).

Comment: When viewing the source of the delivered php page using Firefox, it displays exactly the php source code (no errors at all).  This happens even after replacing php.ini with php.ini-development contents.  Only after including `php_flag display_errors on` does the server run the php code instead of delivering file contents.

Comment: Well than it seems like whenever the `php.ini` is loaded correctly, it does no longer work. It needs an error line to even process php at all? oO
To state an android log mode: "What a Terrible Failure" (aka `wtf`)!
Well anyhow, you can at least check if it really is like that and change this line to something like `php_flag_bla dispbla yikes`... or just about anything else, just to confirm that it needs an error there, and not actually this line (no clue why this should be, but is the only thing I can think of right now, other than that you could just try a recommended `php.ini` from the net).

Comment: Changing the `php_flag` line to your suggestion resulted in php source code being output.  If it needs an error, it needs that specific line to cause the error.  Changing the php.ini file to [this example](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-development) also gives php source output.

Comment: Really interesting! Have you checked the EventViewer again, to see if it logs a specific error when outputting the source code? Other than that you might try a different variant of php.ini still, like the production one from the same page for example: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-production

Comment: Changing to the production version also resulted in php source output.  However, when running `iisreset` and looking in Event Viewer, I noticed this under the System Windows Log: `No usable TLS server certificate for SMTP virtual server instance '1' could be found. TLS will be disabled for this virtual-server.`

Comment: Well that at least is something we can work with! Have you already googled the issue? Following thread deals with the issue and how to get rid of it: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7f531c81-a5a7-45fa-9f22-e2aa440770d7/tls-certificate-issue
While this might not be the full solution for the source-code output, it might be one step towards getting the encryption problems out of the way.

Comment: Well I quickly got in over my head there...  I'll have to take some time to look more into this.  I tried following the instructions but ended up not getting the TLS checkbox for the SMTP server.

Answer (score 1):

**Setting Up and Configuring IIS**

Start by going to the ServerManager on you Server. Most often this is    the server you’ll be running your php website on. Go to Add features    in the Features summary section.  Check SMTP Services in the Add    Features Wizard and hit install. Now wait for the installation to    finish. Open IIS6 (or IIS7) Manager under Administrative Tools ->        Internet Information Services 6.0 in the Start Menu, the          configuration of SMTP makes use of the management console from IIS6.     Under [SMTP Virtual Server], click your right mouse button and select    properties from the context menu. Go to the Access Tab and hit the       Relay button.Add a new entry to the list by clicking the Add       button and enter 127.0.0.1 (or your web server's IP) in the single computer entry       field. Hit Ok two times to apply the new settings.

**Configuring Php**

To make Php send emails you need to make some configurations. Basically there are two options.
In case you’re only going to use the SMTP server in a single project and do not want it to interfere with other projects, you can set the configuration from within your php code by adding the following lines anywhere before sending the email:

```
ini_set('SMTP','localhost' ); 
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'administrator@YourWebsite.com');
```

Another way, to make global use of these settings, add the next lines to your php.ini file.

```
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
sendmail_from = me@example.com
```

Make sure you restart your server after making these changes, to be sure they’re loaded.

This solution is provided here http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/05/31/sending-email-from-php-on-windows-using-iis.aspx on how to set up IIS and php and was provided as answer to this question [500 error when trying to use the MAIL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231214/500-error-when-trying-to-use-the-mail-function)

Comment: The solution is part of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231214/500-error-when-trying-to-use-the-mail-function, so if this is correct maybe it should be marked as duplicate question.

Comment: Trying this, I keep getting `mail(): SMTP server response: 550 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SSL encryption with a port 465:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
```

Comment: That fails the `if( $mail->Send() )` check.

Comment: This is an extraction from Gmail documentation how to configure external email clients for SMTP: Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server - requires TLS or SSL:  smtp.gmail.com;
Use Authentication: Yes;
Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587;
Port for SSL: 465

Comment: That's great, but it's still not working for me.  Is there a link you can point to for this that might go into more detail?

Comment: I advise temporarily to setup a test gmail account in Outlook or Thunderbird to test SMTP settings. At least it does work in my MS Outlook 2007 using SSL with 465 port. If same error, perhaps you have to check firewall or local ISP.

Comment: I can open the Thunderbird client on the server and send an email using the gmail account with no problems.

Comment: Try another version of PHPMailer v.5.2.4: https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/downloads/detail?name=PHPMailer_5.2.4.zip

Comment: Using that version, I get this error: `Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in [filepath]\class.smtp.php on line 248`

Comment: Please don't use old versions. Gmail should use tls on 587, as per the PHPMailer documentation and examples. ssl on 465 is to be avoided.

Comment: @Synchro: Both very good points (old versions & avoid 465)! But for testing purposes / error finding, these are both falid temporary(!) options. And the error he got from trying this (`stream does not support SSL/crypto`) is a better hint to what's the real problem here, than probably any of the other answers so far. Still you are very right to point out that those things are not for production environment!

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: require_once(mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in....

This is the way I had my file routed

Before:
`require_once "mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";`

After:
`require_once "../mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";`

...Same process you would normally do to link an img as background using css.