# Phpmailer how to include it to script?

Tags: php, include, integration, sendmail, phpmailer

I am using PHPmailer [github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), I use the "gmail.php" from the examples and it works perfect when I open it in my browser. But when I copy the code and add it to my existing signup script I get an 500 Error. Also when I try to include it I get an 500 Error. How can I add phpmailer to my existing signup script?

```
<?php
/**
 * This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
 */

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'xxxxxx';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "xxxxxx";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('xxx', 'xxx');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('xx', 'xx');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('Txxx', 'John Doe');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'Welcome to xx!';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

if (!$mail->send()) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: It is just a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Look at your server error log and paste it here

Comment: 500? Messed with your apache config? (or whatever server you use) Post error logs

Comment: To find out the cause of the 500 error, look in your server logs. Also, consider turning on the `error_reporting` and `display_errors` PHP config settings, which will show you the error on screen instead of an uninformative server error. It is very difficult to give any more advice than that without knowing what the actual error is, so do the above, find the real error message, and if you still don't know what to do about it, edit it into your question.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-php-phpmailer/ might help - set it up basically to make it work then add more adventurous bits. Usually mail gets rejected these days if it is not sent by a valid email address on your server.

Comment: file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__)); I would suspect this part - the rest of phpMailer usually causes no problems - you can even attach files easily.This seems to have chapter and verse and might be handy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579546/phpmailer-loads-a-while-then-gives-500-internal-server-error  Try commenting out individual lines to minimise posibilities - keep From and To addresses of course.